# Showing or refuting that $[K(\alpha):K]=n$ and $p(\alpha)=0$, $deg(p(x))=n$ allows to conclude that $p(x)$ is the minimal polynomial.

Tags: field-theory

solving an exercise (specifically problem 14.2.27 of dummit) the following question arose.

Let $K$ a field and $K(\alpha)/K$ extension field with $\alpha\not\in K$ and $ [K(\alpha):K]=n$ and $deg(p(x))=n$ and $p(\alpha)=0$
Is it enough to conclude that $p(x)$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $K$?

Thanks ins advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $p(x)$ is monic, then yes. Observe that $p(\alpha)=0$ implies that the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$, $\min(K,\alpha)$, divides $p(x)$, but since they are of the same degree, $p(x)$ is just a scalar multiple of $\min(K,\alpha)$.